# Seasonality and residuals in not decreasing data

Tags: time-series, seasonality, decomposition

I am analyzing european real estate mutual fund and decided to use simple plot(decompose) command in R to find out about the trend anseasonality effects plus to see residuals.
I got this picture:
[image]

The problem is, the value of mutual fund's share has never decreased, not even once, yet according to the grapf seasonal and residual values did cause some decrease in the share's value.
On the other hand, seasonal and residual values show extremely low values, close to zero, share has value ranging between 0.042 to 0.0625.

The only article I found was that data with values close to zero should not be understood as data with multiplicative seasonalal effect, however when I plotted decomposed data, type = "multiplicative", I saw no difference in the graph of seasonal effect in comparison to additive model.
Thus I am not quite sure how to interpret and explain seasonality and random effects, that both show increasing and decreasing values, when the share's value never decreased.

My only idea is that trend is bigger than seasonal and random effects at every point (maybe skill of fund manager and factors in the economy).

The data are collected on weekly basis (frequency = 52) and obtained since January 2008 to January 2016.

Comment: Well, first the estimated trend is removed from the data, so the seasonality you see is in the detrended series.